# Expo navigation Drawer doesnt open , what can i do to solve this?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

Issue :

Side bar doesnt open when i press the bars icon near navigation Header and i dont recieve any error messages in console.
the bars icon is supposed to trigger a drawer sliding from the left when pressed on.

Code :

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Notifications")}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using expo and came across the same issue, "react-native-reanimated" is added as part of drawer navigation setup ( https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/) and adding the relevant plugin into the babel.config.js resolved the issue e.g.,  `plugins: ["nativewind/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"]`

Comment: yes that's one of the possible solutions in case you missed to add the plug in, but in my case i just had to clean the emulator's data since the drawer worked fine on my physical device.